# Prestashop cache won't clean

Tags: prestashop

Currently I'm working with the newest prestashop version (1.7.x) and the theme called Leo Fashion Store. I'm trying to edit CSS file, however, as soon as I make the edit, changes won't show. It does show immediately after saving the new file but it disappears quickly. It seems the system is taking only cached files.
Caching has been fully disabled through "Performance" settings but it still takes the cached files instead of directly from the main CSS file.
Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use Leo Themes and got the same issue, you should solve it by save again all the theme profiles. You can find the profiles in backoffice under "AP Pagebuilder" menu voice. Hope it helps.

Simone

PS: This is more a comment than an answer but I still cannot comment because of low ranking

Comment: Thanks a lot! Couldn't think of that myself as I wasn't sure if Pagebuilder was related to this issue (though I suspected that it will be the case). Now it works! I would apvote your answer, however, it's not possible due to my rank...

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Theme CSS files are being compressed in a unique minfied CSS (usually stored in theme dir under **assets/css/theme-xxxx.css**) - See the "*Smart CSS cache*" option in the Perfomance Page and make sure it is disabled , or just disable/re-enable it to regenerate the compressed file after your modification.

If this does not help, make sure that there is no CDN or server-level cache that can serve stale date and also make sure that the theme don't use its own dedicated cache for CSS (never seen this in PS 1.7 , though)

Comment: All cache has been disabled and the theme doesn't seem to be using its own cache. After manually deleting the cache files from smarty (other places as well) it simply reappears in 60 seconds... Simone's answer is correct. I just needed to re-save the theme profiles.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the cache, also delete (manually or with a file manager) the **/var/cache/** directory.
it would be easier to understand if you gave us your website address.